# Radare2 webui - need help setting it up

Tags: linux, radare2, websites

How can you set up Radare2 webui in Kali or Ubuntu or any other OS?  I've tried so many different methods but none of them have worked so far.  I think both of them are debian based so that might be the reason it isn't working.  any suggestions on a distro which it would work?

Comment: Have you checked the [open issues](https://github.com/radare/radare2-webui/issues) for r2-webgui? You may need to submit one. It is hard to tell though because no details are provided in the above post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`radare2 -c='H' <binary>` can run radare2 with web interface.
I guess you are using `apt-get` package manager for installing radare2, r2 `deb` package has a bit problem (Web interface files aren't available in deb version), It's better to [install the latest version of radare2 from git](https://rada.re/r/down.html).

[image: Radare 2 Web interface]